# How to handle "switch from" and "switch to" events in X11?

Tags: opengl, x11, xlib, window-management, xrandr

I'm making a fullscreen OpenGL application, and I want it to restore original desktop mode when user switches away from it, and to restore mode back when user switches to it.
This looks like "FocusIn" and "FocusOut" events, but they are not suitable for this. Window will get "FocusOut" as soon as user presses Alt+Tab and window selector appears (because my window is loosing focus at this moment).

Comment: X11 must leave the openGL context and create a new window for the alt-tab dialog, so I find it normal that your application looses the focus. But why do you say that "they are not suitable for this" ? It seems to me that they do pretty much what you want ?

Comment: Because this will switch mode immediately, even if user actually decides not to switch (by selecting in Alt+Tab window my application again).